# compare two file for match, print all matching found

Tags: awk

I am trying to compare each entry of column1 of of File1 against File2 and print both. Column1 of File1 might have duplicate entry. In case of duplicate entry I can see only one output line; but I want both.

My code is `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}; $1 in a {print $0"\t"a[$1]}' File1.txt File2.txt`

File1.txt

```
aa  c   d
aa  c   e
```

File2.txt

```
aa  5
aa  7
aa  9
bb  7
cc  1
```

Expected Output

```
aa  5   aa  c   d
aa  7   aa  c   d
aa  9   aa  c   d
aa  5   aa  c   e
aa  7   aa  c   e
aa  9   aa  c   e
```

What I my code giving

```
aa  5   aa  c   e
aa  7   aa  c   e
aa  9   aa  c   e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for the `join` command:

```
$ join File{1,2}.txt
aa c d 5
aa c d 7
aa c d 9
aa c e 5
aa c e 7
aa c e 9
```

The output's not quite what you want, so let's fix that:

```
$ join File{1,2}.txt | awk '{$1 = $1 FS $NF FS $1; $NF = ""; print}'
aa 5 aa c d
aa 7 aa c d
aa 9 aa c d
aa 5 aa c e
aa 7 aa c e
aa 9 aa c e
```

---

If the input files are not sorted, then (assuming your shell is bash/ksh/zsh)

```
join <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt)
```

See [3.5.6 Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) in the bash manual.

Comment: What if my file is not in sort order?

Answer (score 1):

with `sort/join`

```
$ join <(sort file2) <(sort file1) -o1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2,2.3

aa 5 aa c d
aa 5 aa c e
aa 7 aa c d
aa 7 aa c e
aa 9 aa c d
aa 9 aa c e
```