# what does if(index(i,$12)==1 indicate

Tags: if-statement, indexing, awk

Jus come across an awk script

```
  awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} NR==FNR {a[$1]=($2" "$3);next} {for (i in a) if(index(i,$12)==1) print $0,a[$12]}'
```

in this script what does 
        if(index(i,$12)==1 
mean? Is it indicating true/false condition on just numerical equal to 1?

Comment: This is hard to explain when we do not have any input/output file.  But for the first file it stores field 2 and 3 in an array with index as first field.  Then for second file it loops trough the array to see if it it find match fields.  `if(index(i,$12)==1) `this tells that from data in array value `i` looks if string starts with `==1` text found in field 12 of second file.

Comment: [Awk User's Guide - 9.1.3 String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is your friend.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In this case I do not think it help as much.  Problem is to see how this handles multiple files, array and testing information from various fields. :)

Comment: I was pointing to the `index` reference since the question was `"what does if(index(i,$2)==1 indicate"`, but I agree in the large context, that probably isn't the problem he (or she) needs to solve.

Comment: @Jotne I was trying to compare two files; but there are duplicates in both the input files. hence I was trying to learn how to add a for loop.  I ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875782/compare-two-file-for-match-print-all-matching-found but  the answers were not helpfull for complex files. since both input has duplicates so "for (i in a) if(i~$1) " was not helping. So, I was trying to learn how can I do it. I can use perl, but I was looking for awk solution.

Comment: If you post a question with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you figure out how to do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: @EdMorton I am editing this question.

Comment: Don't do that - you already accepted an answer to the question you asked. Ask a new question rather than invalidating the answers you got (and so opening them up to getting downvotes) by changing this question.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the suggestion. I did not realize that. I am asking a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without samples it is difficult to understand complete requirements of question. Trying it by seeing your code.

`BEGIN`:  section executes before an Input_file is being read.

`OFS=FS` it doesn't make sense to me since both variables by default values will be spaces.

`NR==FNR`: it is the condition when first Input_file is being read.

`a[$1]`: creating an array named a whose index is $1 of current line and value is 2nd and 3rd column of that line with space in them.

`next`: next will skip all further statements for 1dt Input_file from here.

`for(i in a)`: starting a for loop which traverse through all elements of array a.

`index(i,$12)==1`: checking condition if index of array a which was 1st Input_file's 1st column is same as starting point of 12th column. Though it is not guarantee that it will match exact word. It will look match and returns it's starting point so here we are checking if that starting value of matched string is 1.

If above condition is TRUE then printing current line and array a whose index is `$12`.

Answer (score 1):

`index()` is a function. It gets the position of a string within another string. From `man awk`:

> index(s, t)    Return  the index of the string t in the string s, or 0 if t is not present.  (This implies that character indices start at
>                                  one.)  It is a fatal error to use a regexp constant for t.

In your example you iterate over the keys of the array a and check if column 12 starts with the key.